# Scanning on Canon PIXMA MP270 does not work with Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, canon, scanner

After upgrading to ubuntu 14.10 my MP270 no longer scans. Xsane recognises the scanner but does not scan and give a message "Window is not responding". Simple Scan gives a similar result. Printing still works fine.  This has only started happening since upgrading from 14.04. With 14.04 scanning worked perfectly.

Comment: Use Canon's ScanGear MP from Canon's support website.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

Some Canon scanners aren't yet fully supported by sane, especially PIXMA MP devices. (got one myself) However, Canon provides its scanning suite ScanGear MP for Linux. You can download it on Canon's support webiste of your country.

In some countries, including the U.S., the software isn't deployed. So [here](http://de.canon.ch/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP270.aspx)'s the downlaod link from the Canon Switzerland support website.

Download the deb package and install it as you would do with any other. (Install with gdebi, USC, or directly with `sudo dpkg -i <package_file>`)

The package doesn't come with a desktop file, so take the one I made:

```
Name=Canon ScanGearMP
Exec=/usr/bin/scangearmp
Icon=scanner
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Graphics
```

Save it as "scangearmp.desktop" in either `/usr/share/applications/` (for all users) or `~/.local/share/applications/` (only for yourself)